# sum of discrete and absolutely continuous random variables

Tags: probability

We know a sum of two independent absolutely continuous random variables is still absolutely continuous since its density function is the convolution. And without being independent, the sum may be discrete, like $X+(-X)$. My questions are:

1) Can the sum of a discrete and an absolutely continuous random variables be discrete?

And

2) Can the sum of two discrete random variables be absolutely continuous?

It seems to me that for the first condition the density function could be written down if they're independent, but is it still true without independence? And I think since the sum of two discrete set is still discrete, the second situation cannot happen.

Is it right? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the definition of "discrete random variable" as a random variable
taking values in a countable set (not necessarily a discrete set).

The sum of two discrete r.v.'s is discrete, because the sum of two 
countable sets is countable.  So  (2) can't happen.  And then (1) can't happen, because if $X + Y = Z$, $Y = Z - X$.